# cerrando el chat de chatbro con javascript a ciertas horas

Tags: javascript, setinterval

estoy intentando cerrar un chat creado con [chatbro.com][1] al implementarlo en mi web el chat según su documentación posee unas variables que se le pueden añadir al objeto, una de esas variables (allowSendMessages) quitar el input, las siguiente es la implementacion del embebido chat en la web

```
ChatbroLoader({
encodedChatId: '97FfU',
siteDomain: 'codepeo',
allowSendMessages: "true"})
```

en este caso el siguiente código esta enbebido en codepen; la llave de `allowSendMessage` está determinada como true (abierta), lo que busco especificamente es que a cierta hora del día se cierre el chat, esto lo logre por medio de `setinterval`  el inconveniente es que el chat se esta multiplicando

```
function checkDate(){
            var date = new Date();
          console.log(date.getHours())
            if(date.getHours >= "20" || date.getHours() <= "8") {       
        mem = ChatbroLoader({
          encodedChatId: '97FfU',
          siteDomain: 'codepeo',
          allowSendMessages: 'false'
            })
            clearInterval(dateLoop);
            }
          else { 
        mem = ChatbroLoader({
         encodedChatId: '97FfU',
          siteDomain: 'codepeo',
          allowSendMessages: "true"}) 
      }}
       checkDate();
    var dateLoop = setInterval(function() {
        checkDate();
    },60000);
```

Dos soluciones rapidas es quitar el setinterval y dejar que se aplique la condición con la apertura dela página o simplemente quitar el chat a esas horas, la verdad prefiero resolver la multiplicación del chat debido a que si un usuario deja la pagina abierta le chat nunca se cerrara

pd: si se pone el objeto en codepen el chat aparece
[1]: http://chatbro.com

Comment: Deberías crear el chat aparte y cambiar la opción `allowSendMessages` dentro de `checkDate()`,  solo busca en la documentación cómo hacer el cambio.

Comment: @Triby lo intente, pero no hay una forma en la documentación intente llamar el `ChatbroLoader. allowSendMessages = true` no lo reconoce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciertamente, la documentación es muy escasa y hay que experimentar para ver si funciona o no. Como te había comentado, hay que crear el chat solo una vez y, de acuerdo al horario, activar o desactivar el envío de mensajes.

Revisando el enlace que proporcionaste, hay una sección para probar permisos y creo que podría funcionar con lo sugerido al final de la función; incluyo comentarios de cada instrucción.

```
let chat,      // Variable para manipular el chat
    chatOpen;  // Saber si se permiten mensajes o no
function checkDate(start){
    let date = new Date();
    console.log(date.getHours())
    let hours = date.getHours();
    // Permitir mensajes solo dentro del horario
    let allowMsg = (hours > 8 && hours < 20);
    if(start) {
        // Se permiten mensajes?
        chatOpen = allowMsg;
        // Crear chat solo una vez, usando la variable definida arriba
        chat = ChatbroLoader({
            encodedChatId: '97FfU',
            siteDomain: 'codepeo',
            allowSendMessages: allowMsg
        });
        // Crear intervalo
        // Llamando a la función sin parámetros
        let dateLoop = setInterval(checkDate, 60000);
        return;
    }
    // Solo si hay cambio
    if(allowMsg != chatOpen) {
        // Modificar parámetros
        chat.chatParams.allowSendMessages = allowMsg;
        // Actualizar parámetros
        chat.doUpdateEmbedParameters = true;
        // Actualizar ventana de chat
        chat.updateChat();
        // Actualizar variable para saber que el chat permite mensajes o no
        chatOpen = allowMsg;
    }
}
// Verificar hora y crear chat
checkDate(true);
```

Comment: gracias, el chat se cerro a la hora indicada sin duplicarse